# Issue with bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have a little problem with bootstrap tabs.

Please check this [Interior / Exterior](http://lukaszradwan.com/www_architect/services2.php). The content of the first one looks fine, but in the "Exterior" there is a big gap. I need to have it on the same position.

If You could take a look I would be grateful.

This is my content, and for example if I set position:absolute for center_content, left content goes up but the right bar disappears.

```
<div class="center_content border_bottom">

                          <div class="maintitle"><h2>I take my creativity straight from a dream.</h2></div>
                          <div class="text_1">
                              <p>
                                Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts — it is an almost unorthographic life. One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar.

                                </p>
                            </div>
                          <div class="text_2">
                              <p>
                                Etiam sit amet lectus quis est congue mollis. Phasellus congue lacus eget neque. Phasellus ornare, ante vitae consectetuer consequat, purus sapien ultricies dolor, et mollis pede metus eget nisi. Praesent sodales velit quis augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                                <br><br> 
                                Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam. Quisque semper justo at risus. Donec venenatis, turpis vel hendrerit interdum, dui ligula ultricies purus, sed posuere libero dui id orci. 

                                </p>
                            </div>
                          <div class="text_fb">
                              <p class="title">
                                Do You Like Us? Follow Us on Facebook.
                                </p>
                                <div class="fb-like-box fb_iframe_widget" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" data-width="100%" data-height="100%" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="false" data-stream="false" data-show-border="false" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" fb-iframe-plugin-query="app_id=&amp;color_scheme=light&amp;container_width=0&amp;header=false&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FFacebookDevelopers&amp;locale=pl_PL&amp;sdk=joey&amp;show_border=false&amp;show_faces=false&amp;stream=false"><span style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 300px; height: 70px;"><iframe name="f2ce1e0f68" width="1000px" height="1000px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" title="fb:like_box Facebook Social Plugin" src="http://www.facebook.com/v2.0/plugins/like_box.php?app_id=&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2F6Dg4oLkBbYq.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df2c02d98bc%26domain%3Dlukaszradwan.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flukaszradwan.com%252Ff36df8ff4c%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;color_scheme=light&amp;container_width=0&amp;header=false&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FFacebookDevelopers&amp;locale=pl_PL&amp;sdk=joey&amp;show_border=false&amp;show_faces=false&amp;stream=false" class="" style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 300px; height: 70px;"></iframe></span></div>
                          </div> 
                          <div class="image_wrapper" style="margin-bottom: 12px;">
                          <img src="images/services_1.jpg" alt="">
                          </div>

                      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works now, .tab_pane had a display:block, I get rid of it and that's all.